# FDMEE. Exception when I try to load data by fdmAPI.executeQuery

Tags: jython, jython-2.5

I'm trying to retrieve data during AftLoad event:

```
RSet = fdmAPI.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM HYP_CST.dbo.STAGING", [])

while RSet.next():
    do_something()
```

And get the following exception:

```
FATAL [AIF]: Error in CommData.loadData
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4746, in loadData
  File "<string>", line 445, in executeScript
  File "F:\FDMEE/data/scripts/event/AftLoad.py", line 54, in <module>
    while RSet.next():
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Query outputs some rows.
Any help would be appropriated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Jython provided an incorrect error stack. The reason of error was in the procedure do_something() what were not reflected in the stack.